# React native arc slider

Tags: javascript, react-native, slider

***Does anyone know how to make a circle slider like this in react native?***

[image: slider]

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd recommend inserting the example picture in the question itself, rather than linking to external locations that could go stale, or change, which could be confusing.

Comment: @changingrainbows the image wasn't from an external location. SOF uses imgur.com for images. I agree with adding picture in the post and done that as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't specify if third-party libraries are acceptable, so [react-native-circular-slider](https://github.com/bartgryszko/react-native-circular-slider) would be a solid option. It appears to have component props to customize the experience as you require.

If you have to SVG this yourself, then you could use the solution to this [similar question previously posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253804/how-to-make-a-circular-slider-in-react-native).

Comment: I've tried this library but I dont know how to customize it to my needs