# Arc Slider in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, circular-slider

How does one make a Arc/circular slider like this in react native with functional components?
Looking around all i can find are class based instead of functional and my attempts to convert has resulted in handle no longer wanting to move.
Examples i have looked at:

- [rn-circular-slider](https://github.com/hezhii/rn-circular-slider/blob/master/CircularSlider.js)
- [React native arc slider - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507808/react-native-arc-slider)
- [How to make a circular slider in react-native - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253804/how-to-make-a-circular-slider-in-react-native)

[image: Arc Slider Image]

I also cant figure out how to keep the gradient keep going onto the handle like this.
I need to make it so one can drag the handle or click somewhere on the arc to change the value.